# Why are some properties repeated when TRttiContext.GetType is called on a VCL Control?

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.4-sydney

Why are some properties repeated (such as `Action` and `Align`) where others are not (`AlignWithMargins`) when TRttiContext.GetType is called on a VCL Control?

```
uses
  System.RTTI,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.Generics.Defaults;

//....

procedure TForm11.btnShowPropertiesClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRttiContext;
  Props: TArray<TRttiProperty>;
  Prop : TRttiProperty;
begin
  memo1.Clear;
  R := TRttiContext.Create;
  Props := R.GetType(Sender.ClassType).GetProperties;

  //Sort properties by name
  TArray.Sort<TRttiProperty>(props,
    TComparer<TRttiProperty>.Construct(
      function(const Left, Right: TRttiProperty): Integer
      begin
        result := CompareText(Left.Name, Right.Name);
      end
    )
  );

  for prop in Props do
  begin
    try
      Memo1.Lines.Add(
         Prop.Name + ' : ' +
         Prop.PropertyType.ToString + ' = ' +
         Prop.GetValue(Sender).ToString);
    except
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Prop.Name + ' generated an exception');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Output

```
Action : TBasicAction = (empty)
Action : TBasicAction = (empty)
Align : TAlign = alNone
Align : TAlign = alNone
AlignDisabled : Boolean = False
AlignWithMargins : Boolean = False
Anchors : TAnchors = [akLeft,akTop]
Anchors : TAnchors = [akLeft,akTop]
BiDiMode : TBiDiMode = bdLeftToRight
BiDiMode : TBiDiMode = bdLeftToRight
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you would add `Prop.Parent.Name` to the loop that populates the memo you could have easily found out the cause:

```
for prop in Props do
begin
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Add(
       Prop.Parent.Name + '.' + { added }
       Prop.Name + ' : ' +
       Prop.PropertyType.ToString + ' = ' +
       Prop.GetValue(Sender).ToString);
  except
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Prop.Name + ' generated an exception');
  end;
end;
```

The code above produces:

> **TButton**.Action : TBasicAction = (empty)
> **TControl**.Action : TBasicAction = (empty)
> **TControl**.Align : TAlign = alNone
> **TButton**.Align : TAlign = alNone
> **TWinControl**.AlignDisabled : Boolean = False
> **TControl**.AlignWithMargins : Boolean = False
> **TControl**.Anchors : TAnchors = [akLeft,akTop]
> **TButton**.Anchors : TAnchors = [akLeft,akTop]
> **TButton**.BiDiMode : TBiDiMode = bdLeftToRight
> **TControl**.BiDiMode : TBiDiMode = bdLeftToRight
> ...

Now you can clearly see that that [`GetProperties`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType.GetProperties) enumerates properties that were reintroduced in descendant class with higher visibility or altered order. This is typical for controls when `TCustomMyControl` defines `SomeProperty` with `protected` visibility and `TMyControl` reintroduces it at `published` level.

You can try adding interposer class for `TButton` before the `TForm11` declaration:

```
type
  TButton = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton)
  published
    property AlignWithMargins;
  end;
```

The output would reflect the change. I added fully qualified name of property's declaring type (`Prop.Parent.QualifiedName`) to make it more obvious that `TButton` comes from my own unit.

> Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton.Action : TBasicAction = (empty)
> Vcl.Controls.TControl.Action : TBasicAction = (empty)
> Vcl.Controls.TControl.Align : TAlign = alNone
> Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton.Align : TAlign = alNone
> Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.AlignDisabled : Boolean = False
> Vcl.Controls.TControl.AlignWithMargins : Boolean = False
> **Unit1.TButton.AlignWithMargins : Boolean = False**
> Vcl.Controls.TControl.Anchors : TAnchors = [akLeft,akTop]
> Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton.Anchors : TAnchors = [akLeft,akTop]
> Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton.BiDiMode : TBiDiMode = bdLeftToRight
> Vcl.Controls.TControl.BiDiMode : TBiDiMode = bdLeftToRight
> ...

This kind of behavior is not limited to controls. It can be observed on any class that reintroduces properties from an ancestor class.

Comment: great explanation! is there any standard solution to filter out the duplications and retieve only the "top level" properties?

Comment: @tcxbalage That depends on requirements. See also the other answer that suggests using `GetDeclaredProperties`. But it excludes *all* inherited properties and will return only properties declared in the reflected type. Also note that by reintroducing a property you don't override the original property, but you create new one in the derived type. This new property can be completely unrelated to the original one, if you specify a getter or setter.

Comment: @tcxbalage Maybe you'll be fine using [classic RTTI](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo) for enumerating published properties only.

Comment: thx! meanwhile the problem solved, turned out the the GetProperties array already ordered by class hierarchy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980714/delphi-rtti-published-property-appears-twice

Answer (score 6):

Would GetDeclaredProperties() be more useful?

The [help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType.GetDeclaredProperties) states that the difference between GetDeclaredProperties() and GetProperties() is:

> Use the **GetDeclaredProperties** method to obtain a list of all the
> properties that are declared in the reflected type. To obtain the list
> of all properties in the reflected type (including the inherited
> ones), use the GetProperties method instead.

Therefore I would think in your case GetProperties() is working as designed, and returning both properties and inherited properties - hence why some properties are appearing more than once.